# Advanced title capitals functionality available?

Tags: writing, capitalization

Looking at [this page](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html) it seems title-capitals can get reasonably involved. Do packages exist that perform title-caps with support for some of these rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [titlecase](https://github.com/duckwork/titlecase.el) package by Case Duckworth has a reasonable set of rules for various titlecase styles such as APA, MLA, AP, NYT, etc. The package is available on MELPA.

Answer (score 3):

This is a short function that does basic title-capitals:

- Some words aren't capitalized (`the`, `of`, ... etc).
- The 1st word is always capitalized.
- Existing capitalized words are left unchanged (typically acronyms, e.g. `CPU`, `API`, `FIFO` .. etc).
- Characters such as (`\` `-` `'` `.`) prevent the next letter from being capitalized.
- Without a selection it operates on the whole line.
- Colon character capitalizes the following word, even if it would normally be skipped: e.g.
  `Example: The Test Title`
  `Question? The Answer`

---

```el
(defun my-upcase-initials-region ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg nil)
        (end nil)
        (prev-word-end nil)

        ;; Allow capitals for skip characters after this, so:
        ;;   Warning: An Example
        ;; Capitalizes the `An'.
        (chars-skip-reset '(?: ?! ??))
        ;; Don't capitalize characters directly after these. e.g.
        ;; "Foo-bar" or "Foo\bar" or "Foo's".
        (chars-separator '(?\\ ?- ?' ?.))

        (word-chars "[:alnum:]")
        (word-skip
          (list "a" "an" "and" "as" "at" "but" "by"
            "for" "if" "in" "is" "it" "nor" "of"
            "on" "or" "so" "the" "to" "up" "was" "yet"))
        (is-first t))
    (cond
      ((region-active-p)
        (setq beg (region-beginning))
        (setq end (region-end)))
      (t
        (setq beg (line-beginning-position))
        (setq end (line-end-position))))

    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beg)

      (while (< (point) end)
        (setq prev-word-end (point))
        (skip-chars-forward (concat "^" word-chars) end)
        (let ((word-end
                (save-excursion
                  (skip-chars-forward word-chars end)
                  (point))))

          (unless (memq (char-before (point)) chars-separator)
            (let* ((c-orig (char-to-string (char-after (point))))
                   (c-up (capitalize c-orig)))
              (unless (string-equal c-orig c-up)
                (let ((word (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) word-end)))
                  (when
                    (or
                      ;; Always allow capitalization.
                      is-first
                      ;; If it's not a skip word, allow.
                      (not (member word word-skip))
                      ;; Check the beginning of the
                      ;; previous word doesn't reset first.
                      (save-excursion
                        (and
                          (not (zerop (skip-chars-backward "[:blank:]" prev-word-end)))
                          (memq (char-before (point)) chars-skip-reset))))
                    (delete-region (point) (1+ (point)))
                    (insert c-up))))))
          (goto-char word-end)
          (setq is-first nil))))))
```